# Add emplace_back to template class

Tags: c++, templates

I got stuck implementing my own template class where I wanted to add my own implementation of `emplace_back` function. Since I am still learning template design I'll appreciate your input here.

```
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
class MydataStruct
{
public:
    //...
    void emplace_back(Args&&... args)
    {
        //...
        myqueue.emplace_back(args...);
    }
    //...
private:
    std::deque<T> myqueue;
};
```

Sample use:

```
MydataStruct<int> test;
test.emplace_back(1);
```

Whenever I am trying to compile this code I receive error that emplace_back is not defined. It only works with no arguments. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 8):

You should make the [*member function*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions) a [*member function template*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template#Member_function_templates). Use variadic [Forwarding References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward) to capture the arguments, then [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) the arguments to `myqueue.emplace_back`

```
template <typename T>
class MydataStruct
{
public:
    //...
    template<typename ...Args>
    void emplace_back(Args&&... args)
    {
        //...
        myqueue.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    //...
private:
    std::deque<T> myqueue;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is that you put your variadic template in your class' template parameters rather than add one to your method. Try this instead.

```
#include <deque>

template <typename T /*typename ...Args*/>
//        remove this ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
class MydataStruct
{
public:
    //...
    template<typename ...Args>
    // add this ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    void emplace_back(Args&&... args)
    {
        myqueue.emplace_back(args...);
    }
private:
    std::deque<T> myqueue;
};

int bop()
{
    MydataStruct<int> test;
    test.emplace_back(1);
}
```

Edit: Note that this will not do what you want with rvalues. You will need to use [std::forward](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward).

Comment: I see... Thank you very much for clarification.

Comment: Don't just add a note saying why your answer is wrong. Just write a correct answer? Also "rvalue", not "R value"

Answer (score 0):

to get your example to work you would have to do

```
MydataStruct<int,int> test;
test.emplace_back(1);
```

but moving the ...Args to the emplace_back function is the way to go...